# Data link layer Sliding Window utilization formula query

Tags: computer-networks, communication-protocols

In the data link layer, the Sliding Window is used for flow control.

There are two link utilization formula that can be use. They are :

U = 1, for N > 2a + 1

OR

U = N/(1+2a), for N < 2a + 1

In both formula, N denotes the window size and a = Propagation time / transmission time

I am not really understanding which formula to use in what situation although the condition is specified. What does 2a+1 actually mean? Can anyone help me to understand it in  simple term. Thanks!

Comment: What is $a$? And no, you can not use one or the other; they are *one* formula, defining $U$ in a piecewise fashion.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about how we got to the formula, link utilization is the ratio of the time that the link is active to the total time.

> total time being the sum of transmission time and propagation time.
>
> link active time = time taken to transmit N packets = N * TransmissionDelay

Hence, the formula to calculate link utilization(or efficiency) is

> N/(1+2a)

However, in practice, the link utilization cannot exceed 1 (ie link cannot be active for more than 100% of the time).
Hence, whenever N>(1+2a), we restrict the value to 1 only.